# Make OCG layer visible when field isn't empty?

Tags: pdf, acrobat

Is it possible to check when a field is not empty and if not, make an ocg layer visible?

```
var ocg = FindOCG("Item 1 Arrow");
if (+event.value === '') {
    ocg.state = !ocg.state;
} else {
    ocg.state = !ocg.state;
}
```

Something like this (which doesn't work)!

Answer (score 0):

Put this in the custom format script of the field in question. Replace "Square" with the name of your layer. You can see an example of it working [here](http://dev.datalogics.com/cookbook/document/CircleSquare.pdf).

```
function getOCGByName(cName, nPage) {
    var ocg = null;
    var ocgArray = this.getOCGs(nPage);
    for (var i=0; i < ocgArray.length; i++) {
        if (ocgArray[i].name == cName) {
            ocg = ocgArray[i];
        }
    }
    return ocg;
}

var field = event.target;
var ocg = getOCGByName("Square", this.pageNum);
if (field.value.length > 0) {
    ocg.state = true;
}
else {
    ocg.state = false;
}
```

**Note:** This will only work in Adobe Acrobat and Reader and a few other viewers that are JavaScript capable.